# Solr MultiPhraseQuery Not Returning Correct Results

Tags: search, solr, shingles

I am having trouble creating a Solr search for substrings. For example, when a user searches for "Alfa Romeo Land Car", I want to only match complete brands (only "Alfa Romeo", **not** "Land Rover"). The way I am trying to do this is by creating shingles from my query and then trying to do an exact match against my "car brands" Solr core.

So if a user searches for "A B C", I would like to get the shingles [A, AB, ABC, B, BC, C].

But when I use the Solr configuration below, when I search for "A B C" (using EDisMax or the standard query parser) Solr returns nothing, but if search for "ABC" I get the matching result "ABC".

Here is my schema.xml file:

```
<field name="id"             type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="name"           type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="seoAlias"       type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>


<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="0" generateWordParts="0" catenateAll="1" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="0" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" tokenSeparator="" maxShingleSize="5"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Here are the documents in my Solr core:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 7,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A B C D",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524585748644233200
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "A B C",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524586301229105200
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "B C D",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524586311147585500
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A B",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524586322261442600
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "B C",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524586329997836300
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "C D",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524586338173583400
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "B",
        "seoAlias": "abce",
        "_version_": 1524652609127841800
      }
    ]
  },
```

In the Solr admin webpage, if I go to "Schema Browser", then select the field in question, and press "Load Term Info" I can see the following indexed terms:

```
6
 /6 Top-Terms:  
1
ABC
ABCD
BC
BCD
CD
AB
```

When I search for "A B C" I want the following shingles [ABC AB BC A B C]
but from debug query I get:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "*:*",
    "querystring": "*:*",
    "parsedquery": "MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)",
    "parsedquery_toString": "*:*",
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
    "filter_queries": [
      "name:\"A B C\""
    ],
    "parsed_filter_queries": [
      "**MultiPhraseQuery**(name:\"(A AB ABC) (B BC) C\")"
    ],
```

I think that the problem may be related to **MultiPhraseQuery**. It creates what appear to be the correct shingles, but it seems that Solr does not search with these string. Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot in advance